# How to make a fully responsive background image that works even in iPhone Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, responsive-design

I tried different methods, mostly people suggest to use `img` instead of a `background-image` to get the perfect result, but I was wondering is it possible to fix this with just some tricks and have a full-width background image?

[Here's my live website that I have problem with](http://web.signvalue.ca/)

Comment: Check out [this link](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/), quite good method if you didn't tryied it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not need the img to fill the page vertically and I think that you want the whole image to fit horizontally this is how I would do it.

```
body { 
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/x131ofex/3/